# Unable to check the status of Google OAuth consent screen verification process

Tags: google-classroom, google-cloud-console

I submitted the consent screen with some Sensitive scopes (classroom.courses etc) around more than 1 month back and after 1 day i get the message from google that i have to verified the domains so i complete the verification process of domain and submit it again after 2 days. Till now my consent screen is not verified. In OAuth consent screen verification page it shows just this text 'Your consent screen is being verified. This may take up to several days. Your last approved consent screen is still in use' but didnt mention any time frame.

Anyone know from where i get the status of this verification process. It is mentioned that it will takes some weeks if the apps uses some sensitive scopes but still after 5 to 6 weeks i didn't get any notification from google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should receive an email from Google with the subject "OAuth Verification Request" stating that your project has been successfully verified.  However, in all my cases for Android/iOS projects I first received an email asking me to create a video on YouTube demonstrating the use of the sensitive scopes in the app.  After I created that, approval arrived in a few days.
For one of my projects, I never received any email update so I just made some small change to Oauth screen and resubmitted.  I then heard back in a few days, so I think for some reason the one verification request got lost.
You can also try respond to the first email you received from google regarding the verification of the domain.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. Presently waiting on status of a request as well. Will update when I had a timeline data point to share.